# what is viewport in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

anyone please briefly explain what viewport is in Extjs Javascript library? or provide a link which explains the basics.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Viewport is a container that automatically resizes itself to the size of the whole browser window. You can then add other ExtJS UI components and containers in it.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [this page.](http://examples.extjs.eu/). Go to Layouts > Simple Viewport for demo

Comment: really useful examples it cleared my all doubts,I am looking for similar examples but i am using legacy version(Extjs 2.1),do you have any links ?

Answer (score 0):

A specialized container representing the viewable application area (the browser viewport).

The Viewport renders itself to the document body, and automatically sizes itself to the size of the browser viewport and manages window resizing. There may only be one Viewport created in a page.

Like any Container, a Viewport will only perform sizing and positioning on its child Components if you configure it with a layout.

A Common layout used with Viewport is border layout.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Viewport